# What does in vec and out vec means?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

In GLSL I didnt understood what is "in" and "out" variables, what does it mean?
Here is a sample of my code that I copied from a tutorial.

```
// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "in vec3 color;"
    "out vec3 Color;"
    "void main() {"
    "   Color = color;"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec3 Color;"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "void main() {"
    "   outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);"
    "}";
```

Comment: **unclear what you're asking** Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: "in vec" and "out vec" are *not* related to the "C language" at all. Rather, the text inside the strings is [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language), which is *not* C (or C++) even though GLSL was designed to "provide many operators familiar to those with a background in using the C programming language".

Comment: @user2864740: `const GLchar*` and string literals are, however. It does not really matter a whole lot, but this code clearly is not something like Java because string concatenation does not work that way in Java.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Touché

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared `in` and `out` at "file" scope like that refer to stage input/output.

1. In a vertex shader, a variable declared `in` is a vertex attribute and is matched by an integer location to a vertex attribute pointer in OpenGL.
2. In a fragment shader, a variable declared `in` should match, by name, an output from the vertex shader (same name, but `out`).
3. In a fragment shader, a variable declared `out` is a color output and has a corresponding color attachment in the framebuffer you are drawing to.

In your vertex shader, you have two vertex attributes (`position` and `color`) used to compute the ***interpolated*** input in the fragment shader (`Color`). The fragment shader writes the *interpolated* color to the color buffer attachment identified by `outColor`.

It is impossible to tell what vertex attributes `position` and `color` and what color buffer `outColor` are associated with from your shader code. Those must be set in GL code through calls like `glBindAttribLocation (...)` and `glBindFragDataLocation (...)` prior to linking.